# How can I test Web service without any automation tool and only using manual

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, testcase, rest

I am a manual tester and my responsibility is the web, mobile application testing in which I need to test a web service but I have not used any automation tools yet.

Please suggest me a manual way to perform web service testing. Thanks in advance.

The web service is **REST**.

Comment: We have used REST type of Web service.

Comment: In case of REST you need a browser plugin (or Fiddler or other tool) to manage the different type of messages to the server. To handle the JSON files, XML files manually will be a nightmare very quickly, so I suggest that invest a little time to learn how to use these tools.

Comment: GET requests can be tested with just Web browser, POST, DELETE, PUT request will require tool, e.g. Postman plugin for browser or curl command line tool. There's no way to do this without any tool because you're actually mimicking a machine, a programmed client.

Comment: Very carefully with magnets, a bit of copper coil, a stop watch, and direct access to the ethernet cable...

Comment: Strictly speaking, @atk is right, of course. But a more comfortable way would be like this: `$ telnet example.com 80`; `GET /index.html HTTP/1.0`, ; ``  (empty line).

Comment: @atk Luckily, any normal gigabit ethernet port is backwards compatible to 10BASE-T... but it may still require some training. And an assistant with Parkinson disease, taking care of the clock, will surely help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the REST service testing [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and [HttpMaster](http://www.httpmaster.net/) are good tools. It supports dynamic parameters, validation of response data, various data viewers, etc. If you are looking for performing load testing of the REST services than [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/features.html#Standards) and [JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) open source tools can be considered.

This data is taken from the post

[Tools for REST webservice testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13111/tools-for-rest-webservice-testing)

Comment: +1: I use cURL command-line tool.

Comment: I'm suspicious of clicking on that "Grinder" link ¬_¬

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using an open source tool such as http://www.soapui.org/

This will allow you to send requests to your end points and, in turn, see the responses.  Should you choose to extend your test from manual into automated (ie run the same test again along with other tests) then SoapUI also gives you that option.

Comment: I think he suggested that his application use REST not SOAP. So, I dont think SoapUI is suitable for this case.

Comment: SoupUI can be used for any restful services, not just Soap.  If you wish it also supports (HTTP GET, POST, DELETE, PUT).  They are renaming the product to ReadyAPI to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 1):

[cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/).

I recommend using this command-line tool for the following reasons:

- it allows both developers and other testers to reproduce your test or issue you have found by just copy-pasting your command to their console.
- it is available on most platforms: Windows, Linux, MacOs.
- many tools like [POSTMan](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/creating_curl), [Network Panel in Chrome Developer Tools](https://coderwall.com/p/-fdgoq/chrome-developer-tools-adds-copy-as-curl), [FireBug in Firefox](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/planet-mozilla/firebug-tip-resend-http-request/), [Charles Proxy](https://lornajane.net/posts/2015/proxy-curl-through-charles-proxy) have an option to copy a recorded HTTP Request as cURL command.

Here's an example of curl command:

```
curl http://httpbin.org/post --data "some-data" -v
```

together with HTTP Request sent:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 23.21.245.14...
* Connected to httpbin.org (23.21.245.14) port 80 (#0)
> POST /post HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: httpbin.org
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 9
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 9 out of 9 bytes
```

and HTTP Response received:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: keep-alive
* Server gunicorn/19.7.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: gunicorn/19.7.1
< Date: Tue, 02 May 2017 12:39:15 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Content-Length: 387
< Via: 1.1 vegur
<
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {
    "some-data": ""
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "9",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.37.1"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "88.221.209.14",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
* Connection #0 to host httpbin.org left intact
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned here, there are lot of open source tools like SOAP UI etc.. and plugins like POSTMAN, RESTCLIENT etc... which can be used to send GET/POST request and check response. 
Other than these, if you are comfortable using java, you can write a simple code using httpclient library to send GET/POST request and validate the response. At the same time you can create a simple Data Driven test where you can have variety of requests, this will help you in increasing the test coverage.

If its works for you, I can post a simple example also.

Answer (score 0):

You want to test the web service manually, and unfortunately it is only possible with some interface. Web services are not visible and only applications can communicate with this.
So my suggestion is test the Applications  that are using the web services.
Doing so you will be indirectly test the web services.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a rest posting addin. You can also use Excel VBA httppost capability.

Comment: You need to provide more information to make this a good answer.